# vbscript and secure connection

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, security, remote-access

I don't know if anyone has been able to connect to a secure mssql server over the internet with vbscript using the adodb object

is there pilicy that restrict script connecting to secure servers?

Comment: Is the server behind a firewall?  If so, you would need to tunnel through that first.

Comment: @uslackr i can connect to the same server using visual studio 2010 with the same connection string, without any problem. i would have posted a connection string along with the question, but by then it would be a programming problem and not fit in here.

Comment: how are you handling the password?

Comment: i set persistent security info to false in the connection string

Comment: also when you say a secure mssql server, secure in what sense?

Comment: also go ahead and post the connection string.

Comment: Data Source=www.serveraddress.com,port;Integrated Security=True;User ID=myid;password=mypassword;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True

Comment: @tony the server is configured to accept only secure connection through ssl

Comment: what error message?

Comment: `"The requested action with this object has failed."`

Comment: and this error is on the line number that corresponds to the connection being created?

Comment: the line number `84` is the number of the connection object e.g **objAdobHandle.open(connectionstring)**

Answer (score 0):

If the server has been setup with a certificate then you can add "Encrypt=yes;" to the connection string which will encrypt the connection over the network.  If you want to force encryption for all connections then enable the "force encryption" option and restart the instance and all connections will be encrypted.

Comment: i have tried this, but it fails

Comment: What error message are you getting?  Can you connect from the native tools over a secure connection?  If you have force encrypted enabled, then no changed to the connection string are needed.

Answer (score 0):

btw the answer to this question "is there pilicy that restrict script connecting to secure servers?"  is no!